# Autoload a class within a class in Joomla using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, autoload

I'm writing a Joomla module.

As part of this I'm using an ajax call (using 3.x)

the ajax etc works fine.  However I want to use an object autoloader within the ajax class but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong (it works fine as standalone code just breaks implementing with Joomla and ajax)

I have this for the Joomla class:

```
    public function getAjax()
        {
            $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
            $cmd  = $input->get('cmd');

            if($cmd =="setPayment"){
             require  __DIR__ . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';
             use PayPal\Api\Amount;     
             use PayPal\Api\Details;
```

The code cannot find the Amount and Details classes.  I'm assuming that it's to do with the context I'm calling them.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you have an error message for us?

Comment: The only error that's thrown is a 500 page error.  However when I take out the use  from the code the page loads fine.  Dreamweaver has an unexpected use(T_use)

Comment: I'm not a Joomla guy, but does Joomla have a PSR autoloader configured. Where is it configured, and is the Paypal library PSR compatible. Those are your starting points.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions

Comment: _The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped._ http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: @Chay22 oh man. I didn't even see the "use" when reading the code. Nice catch. I would give that as an answer.

Comment: @cgTag I think you've picked the right bit out although I haven't got it to pick up the classes yet - I guess I need to figure out how to use the Joomla PSR